# PostgreSQL docker container suddenly failing to start

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, timescaledb

I have a Docker container (based on `timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest`) that I start like this:

```
docker run -d --name timescaledb -p 127.0.0.1:5432:5432 \
-v /Users/<me>/timescaledb-data:/home/postgres/pgdata/data \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14-latest
```

Today, on trying to run this script, Docker complains:

```
2023-11-05 19:43:48 2023-11-05 19:43:48.439 UTC [1] FATAL:  data directory "/home/postgres/pgdata/data" has wrong ownership
2023-11-05 19:43:48 2023-11-05 19:43:48.439 UTC [1] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

I have changed *nothing* since I successfully launched it yesterday. I have now of course tried to reset the permissions on that folder.

This is on macOS 14.2 with Docker Desktop 4.25.0 (126437)

I am not even sure what the error indicates. Is it referring to the PostgreSQL server?

Comment: Run in the container this command : `id ; ls -ld /home/postgres/pgdata/data` and post result.

Comment: But the container will not launch

Comment: Aha I see, sorry, interactive mode: uid=1000(postgres) gid=1000(postgres) groups=1000(postgres),101(ssl-cert)
drwx------ 27 root root 864 Nov  5 20:03 /home/postgres/pgdata/data

Comment: I tried to change the group to postgres on that folder on my machine, but it does not exist. Why do I need to create it? This was working yesterday. What could have happened? Can I run docker with a different user?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following in the container itself and it has resolved the issue:

`chown -R postgres:postgres /home/postgres/pgdata/data`

I was pretty sure that would not work, but it did.